# Tkinter - Pillow library - TypeError 'dict' object not callable when opening image

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I get an error when using Pillow  libary for opening a .png image in Tkinter.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
root.title("MainWindow")
root.iconbitmap('tkinter_programicon.ico')

my_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.OPEN("image.png"))
my_label = Label(image=my_image)
my_label.pack()

exit_button = Button(root, text="Exit Program", command=root.quit)
exit_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

ERROR:
my_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.OPEN("image.png"))
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

How can I solve this?

Comment: `Image.OPEN(...)` should be `Image.open(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

You should change the `my_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.OPEN("image.png"))` line to `my_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("image.png"))`.